# Best way to store/retrieve service properties

Tags: lagom

What is the best way to store/retrieve configurations related to the microservice?
How to get for instance, the IP and port serving the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your service orchestration tool. The IP/port of your service instance may change during its lifetime, as instances can be added, removed, moved etc.
Other services communicating with yours would retrieve the necessary information through a service lookup mechanism.